# What is the best filesystem for log files on Linux?

Tags: linux, filesystems, log-files

What file system would you choose for your `/var/log` directory ?

Upd:

this is for a typical medium-load web/mail/ftp server. `ext3/ext4` works just fine, but I have been thinking of other filesystems too. Main considerations are as following:

- Log files are mostly written to. Reads are rare.
- Underlying media is a typical hard disk drive.
- No reliability requirements. If some files get corrupted, this won't be a big problem.
- Logs are rotated on a daily basis. Logs for each day are saved in separate files. Older logs are deleted after six months.

Comment: "No reliability requirements. If some files get corrupted, this won't be a big problem." -- Really? It seems odd that you care about your logs enough to worry about what fs to use, but don't really care if they get corrupted.

Comment: @ErikA - perhaps Gart is merely looking for the fastest fs available?

Comment: @warren - perhaps. It just seems like the priorities are a bit skewed. To each his own, though.

Comment: @ErikA - I agree... personally I think logs are important enough to want to hold onto for some amount of time, but if you only need them for a very short period of time, then I guess it doesn't matter :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use ext3 making sure you mount it with the `noatime` option and possibly with the `data=writeback` option.

(Otherwise I wouldn't spend too much time considering the question unless you are experiencing specific performance problems.)

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I just go with the default for my platform (ext3 most often on Linux).

Answer (score 1):

As the number of log files is usually low but individual files can be quite big I would go for the most resilient FS: ext3, if your log files are really big (in the order of few gigabytes) XFS should be considered.